# Custom UITableViewCells occasionally remain highlighted and do not push next view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells, most of the time when they're touched, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is called, and a new view is pushed.  However, sometimes when they are tapped in a certain way (tap and hold for about a second), they will just remain highlighted and not push the next view until another tap is detected anywhere else on the screen. I have tried logging a message within didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and confirmed that it is not being called in these instances. The code within that method is :

```
PortfolioVC *portfolioController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"portfolioIdentifier"];
AccountInformationVC *accountController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"accountIdentifier"];
[[Globals Variables] setIndex:indexPath.row];

if (indexPath.section == 0)
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:accountController animated:YES];
if (indexPath.section == 1)
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:portfolioController animated:YES];
```

The highlighted image is set within the xib for the custom UITableViewCell by connecting the selectedBackground to the UIImageView containing the highlighted image.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I had to reconnect the background UIImageViews in the custom cell xibs. After doing that, cleaning the build, and deleting the app, the problem was fixed. I also had tried to override the setSelected and setHighlighted methods in the custom UITableViewCells, and deleted those methods.